# WildFly Deployment error

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-wildfly-11

I'm currently moving up my project to wildfly 11.  When i try to make my workspace up it's showing the following error

```
    FINE  [org.apache.cxf.resource.DefaultResourceManager] (MSC service thread 1-2) resolving resource <org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl/bus> type <interface org.apache.cxf.Bus>
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MYAPP.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MYAPP.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "MYAPP.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172) [wildfly-server-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032) [jboss-msc-1.2.7.SP1.jar:1.2.7.SP1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955) [jboss-msc-1.2.7.SP1.jar:1.2.7.SP1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/COMM_FAILURE
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:115)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:101)
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:43)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.injection.JBossWSResourceInjectionResolver.resolve(JBossWSResourceInjectionResolver.java:54)
    at org.apache.cxf.resource.DefaultResourceManager.findResource(DefaultResourceManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.cxf.resource.DefaultResourceManager.resolveResource(DefaultResourceManager.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.resolveResource(ResourceInjector.java:442)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.visitMethod(ResourceInjector.java:226)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.annotation.AnnotationProcessor.processMethods(AnnotationProcessor.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.annotation.AnnotationProcessor.accept(AnnotationProcessor.java:72)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:118)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:112)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.loadAndRegister(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:242)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.getBeanOfType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:320)
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.getExtension(ExtensionManagerBus.java:215)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.BusHolder.setWSDLManagerStreamWrapper(BusHolder.java:470)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.configuration.BusHolder.configure(BusHolder.java:156)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.startDeploymentBus(BusDeploymentAspect.java:97)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.deployment.aspect.BusDeploymentAspect.start(BusDeploymentAspect.java:59)
    at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.AspectDeploymentProcessor.deploy(AspectDeploymentProcessor.java:73)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165) [wildfly-server-3.0.8.Final.jar:3.0.8.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE from [Module "deployment.MYAPP.war" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198) [jboss-modules.jar:1.6.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412) [jboss-modules.jar:1.6.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400) [jboss-modules.jar:1.6.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116) [jboss-modules.jar:1.6.1.Final]
    ... 34 more

ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "MYAPP.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"MYAPP.war\".INSTALL" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"MYAPP.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/omg/CORBA/COMM_FAILURE
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE from [Module \"deployment.MYAPP.war\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"MYAPP.war\".beanmanager"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"MYAPP.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"MYAPP.war\".beanmanager]",
        "jboss.deployment.unit.\"MYAPP.war\".batch.artifact.factory is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"MYAPP.war\".beanmanager]"
    ]
}
```

I have some web services and after that it is showing the above error.Can any one tell how to dealt with this.

Comment: It seems that you've multiple dependencies that are missing in the WAR file that is deployed.

Comment: can you tell me required dependencies to make the war get deployed.